Underlying Reason for Why ranges::filter_view is Modifiable but ranges::transform_view is not
I've been exploring C++20 ranges and views and used the cppinsights.io website to dig into the details. I noticed something interesting about how filter_view and transform_view behave differently when trying to modify the elements in a range.
Now if you paste the code below into the cppinsights.io website, you'll notice that the type of iterators (__begin1, __end1) causes different modification behavior and the reason why transform_view is read-only. Is my observation correct? Can someone explain it?"
//For transform_view:
        
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    auto transformedView = numbers | std::views::transform([](int n) { return n * 2; });

    for (auto&& value : transformedView) {
        value += 1; // won't modify
    }

    for (const auto& num : numbers) {
        std::cout << num << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}

//for filter
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    auto filterView = numbers | std::views::filter([](int n) { return n%2== 0; });

    for (auto&& value : filterView) {
        value += 1;  //  modify
    }


    for (const auto& num : numbers) {
        std::cout << num << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}

https://cppinsights.io/
https://cppinsights.io/

Why do you expect the result of n * 2 to be modifiable?

n % 2 == 0is not modifiable, and it is not the elements of filter

you are modifying temporary returned from transform, while filter returns element matching the condition

@cpplearner but i can modify the result of filter in the code example .

A transform view returns the result of a function. In your case, you are returning the result of n * 2. This is prvalue int, with no association to the ints stored in numbers. Of course modifying this has no effect on numbers.
If you have a transform that returns a mutable reference, then you can modify through it.
struct number {
    number(int value): value(value) {}
    int value;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<number> numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    auto transformedView = numbers | std::views::transform([](number& n) -> int& { return n.value; });

    for (auto&& value : transformedView) {
        value += 1; // does modify
    }

    for (const auto& num : numbers) {
        std::cout << num.value << " ";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}


Thanks Caleth. So how about a filter view? It is also just a view but how come data can be modifiable there? and also we return values there. don't we?

I think I got it finally! In the first example using std::ranges::transform_view, the transformation function returns a transformed value, which is not the original element from the underlying range but a newly computed value (in this case, x * x). The resulting value from the transformation is a temporary object (an rvalue).

In the second example using std::ranges::filter_view, the lambda function only filters elements but doesn't modify them. The filter_view simply provides access to the original elements in the range (numbers) that meet the filter criteria. Since these are actual elements from the original range (numbers), so they can be modified.

@Sami yes, that's the difference
